# How to properly convert an dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument to CLOB when said document contains special characters

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

Consider the following SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/888bc/1 , which hosts the following PL/SQL function:

```
create or replace function GetSymbol return clob is
  v_domdocument dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
  v_root_node   dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
  v_root_child  dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
  v_text        dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
  v_xmltype     xmltype;
begin
  v_domdocument := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument;
  dbms_xmldom.setVersion(v_domdocument, '1.0" encoding="UTF-8');
  dbms_xmldom.setCharset(v_domdocument, 'UTF-8');
  v_root_node  := dbms_xmldom.makeNode(v_domdocument);
  v_root_child := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(v_root_node,
                                          dbms_xmldom.makeNode(dbms_xmldom.createElement(v_domdocument, 'root')));
  v_text       := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(v_root_child,
                                          dbms_xmldom.makeNode(dbms_xmldom.createTextNode(v_domdocument, NCHR(8364)))); -- Euro symbol
  v_xmltype    := dbms_xmldom.getxmltype(v_domdocument);
  return v_xmltype.getClobVal;
end;
```

If I perform the following SELECT statement:

```
select GetSymbol from dual;
```

...then SQLFiddle returns the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <root>€</root>
```

So far so good. However, if I try this on my Oracle 11g database, I suddenly get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <root>¿</root>
```

That is, somewhere along the conversion between NVARCHAR2 --> dbms_xmldom.DOMNode/dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument --> xmltype --> CLOB , the Euro symbol gets "transformed" into an inverted question mark as seen above.

Any idea of what's going on and how I can work around this? My goal is to return an XML where the Euro symbol is properly shown.

Comment: What is your database character set and national character set, which client are you using, and what encoding is the client and operating system using? It may just be a display issue. (Also curious - do you actually need `NCHR(8364)`, rather than `unistr('\20ac')`, since the document is UTF-8 anyway?)

Comment: From what I can gather, by selecting from V$NLS_PARAMETERS: NLS_CHARACTERSET=WE8DEC and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET=AL16UTF16. Also, I'm using Allroundautomations' PL/SQL Developer Version 10.0.5.1710 on Windows 8.

Comment: To answer your other question, I don't need `NCHR(8364)`. However, `unistr('\20ac')` yields the same result on my client.

Comment: I think you should still be able to use `unistr('\20ac')` to generate the symbol. But the problem is how your client shows it - or rather, that it can't. (Try `select NCHR(8364), unistr('\20ac') from dual` - that will show the same non-character for both, I think; so nothing to do with XML. But you can `dump()` the final CLOB to see what it really has.) I'm not familiar with how but you probably need to change the PL/SQL Developer settings to use Unicode or a specific translation, akin to NLS_LANG.